# How to create view controller that covers half the screen programmatically SWIFT

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, programmatically-created

I am trying to create a view similar to Facebook so that when you click a button, a view controller covers half the sceeen like this:[image: half view]

And then if you swipe up it covers the whole view like this:

[image: full view]

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use an container view , and set frame of container view half of the screen height 
. but you can just use container view in object library xcode.
container view is look like view use in your view controller class bellow the class name add this code :

```
  class YourViewController: UIViewController {
  // MARK: Properties
  let containerView = UIView()
```

in your viewDidLayoutSubviews() function you should set frame of container view like this  :

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.midY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 2)
 let yourSecondViewController = YourSecondViewController()
    addContentContainerView(yourSecondViewController)
}
```

now you have a container view that cover half of the screen,
then you should add your second view controller to your container view ,
so you should create a second view controller class  programmatically , or you should create a view controller in your xcode storyboard and set storyboard id for that.

for add and remove a child view controller in an container view you can use this functions:

```
    private func addContentContainerView(_ childViewController: UIViewController) {


    childViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
    containerView.addSubview(childViewController.view)

    self.addChildViewController(childViewController)
    childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

}
private func removeContentContainerView(_ childViewController: UIViewController) {
    childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    childViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    childViewController.removeFromParentViewController()


}
```

then you should add your second view controller to your container view with private func addContentContainerView(_ childViewController: UIViewController)

if you make the second programmatically and set you should use this code for use add that in your container in your viewWillLayoutSubviews method like this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.midY, width:      self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 2)
let yourSecondViewController = YourSecondViewController()
addContentContainerView(yourSecondViewController)
}
```

but if you make your second view controller in storyboard you should set id for that , select view controller then select identity inspector  below identity set Storyboard ID : SecondViewController 
then instead last viewWillLayoutSubwies , your viewWillLayoutSubviews should like this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.midY, width:      self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 2)
 let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let yourSecondViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
addContentContainerView(yourSecondViewController)

}
```

and for scroll that you should add a UIScrollView and set height of that to self.view.frame.height * 1.5